# Running a shell script inside another shell script with different user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two shell scripts:

**one.sh**

```
echo "hello"
su - oracle -c "sh /tmp/two.sh" 
echo "good bye"
```

**two.sh**

```
echo "bla bla bla"
```

i want to run "one.sh" as "root" and see this output:

```
hello
bla bla bla
good bye
```

How that can be possible?

Comment: you want to login as another user from bash script?

Comment: yes, also want to get output from there.

Comment: try: `su - oracle -c /tmp/two.sh` and tell what the output is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set `chmod +x` to your scripts

try:

```
echo "hello"
su - oracle -c /tmp/two.sh
echo "good bye"
```

Comment: i don't need password when logging from root to oracle user.

Comment: Ok how did you see top of my answer part?

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
su - oracle -c "sh two.sh"
```

the interpreter doesn't know the path of file "two.sh".

Try with absolute path... (for example, sh /tmp/two.sh").

So:

```
root@myServer:/tmp# ./one.sh
hello
bla bla bla
good bye
```

**UPDATE**

Please check also that "sh" can be found by oracle user... Otherwise, specify absolute path for "sh", too...

Comment: i've already tried this way but it didn't work. also i'm sorry for not mentioning it in the question. i edited it.

my problem is, when i run this script, i can't see "bla bla bla" in my console.

Comment: Strange, it's working for me...

Comment: Obviously the comments in shell should start with a "#", "//this command doesn't show me any output" is an illegal comment, an produces a syntax error... :-)

Comment: there is no comment in my actual script :)